# Angular - 2 way form complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm building a web app , and i have an issue, user have 2 ways to complete the form , and i don't know how to declare this on my controllers , 
i used ng-show and ng hide for the two way.  thank you for helping me

```
<div class="list">
      <div class="item item-icon-left title"> <i class="icon ion-social-euro"></i> Budget in your mind</div>
      <div class="row checkbox">
        <div class="col col-50 ">
          <div class="item item-checkbox" ng-click="showme=true">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="radio" checked name="group">
            </label>
            Fix Price</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-50">
          <div class="item item-checkbox" ng-click="showme=fasle">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="radio" name="group">
            </label>
            Price Per Hour</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-hide="showme">
        <select>
          <option selected>Basique (5 - 8 euros)</option>
          <option>standard (8 - 12 euros)</option>
          <option>qualifié (12 - 22 euros)</option>
          <option>expert (> 22 euros)</option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </label>
```

Comment: good morning from france and thank you again

Answer (score 2):

its looking like spelling mistake :

```
<div class="col col-50">
      //change showme to false instead of fasle
      <div class="item item-checkbox" ng-click="showme=false">//not fasle
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="radio" name="group">
        </label>
        Price Per Hour</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you for you quick answer but its  not working with an another value than false , i think i didnt explain the problem well ( maybe my bad english) so , when i click to a checkbox to an another , all work well
the views changes , now i'm building the script to validate the form , but i dont know how to declare to the controller that i have 2 way form complete

Comment: you will be having $scope.showme as true or false to decide which way to complete form

Comment: is that simple ...thank you very much , i'm gonna test it ;
have a great day

Answer (score 0):

You use **ng-click** instead of **ng-show**,
Just Change **ng-click** to **ng-show** in your code